# How can I resolve these vbulletin 404 errors using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, vbulletin

I have a very big forum (230k threads, 3 million posts) that has a large number of 404 pages reported on Google Webmaster Tools, to the tune of about 14,000 404 URLs. Google is probably showing these 404s because I have incoming links to them, meaning I'm losing a lot of SEO benefit by not having these links follow through to the actual page.

I know why I have this problem, a year ago the URLs on my site were changed back to vBulletin default so that they look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/showthread.php?t=323653&p=4230256
```

I would like to keep them this way since they've been that way for a year. The problem is that there were two previous formats that are showing 404 errors:

These:

```
http://www.domain.com/forums/showthread.php?t=21461

http://www.domain.com/forums/showthread.php?t=16187
```

Which just need to have `forums/` removed from the URL, and these:

```
http://www.domain.com/forums/f8/39840-infractions_system_how_works.html

http://www.domain.com/forums/f11/67410-viewing_ijji_gunz_replays_while_offline.html
```

Which are a funky URL structure that was created back when I had vbSEO installed.

`/forums/` needs to be removed and I think that the numbers 39840 and 67410 are probably the thread id. I think there's everything we need in the URL to rewrite but I'm not entirely sure how to achieve it using htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, your `.htaccess` is located at website root "/"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# removes "forums/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/showthread.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]+)$ $1 [R=301,NC,L]

# parses thread id
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/showthread.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^forums/[^/]+/(\d+)-.*$ showthread.php?t=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# to redirect /forums/f8/39840-something.html to
# /showthread.php?t=39840
RewriteRule ^forums/[^/]+/([^-]+)-[^.]+\.html$ /showthread.php?t=$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]

# to redirect /forums//showthread.php?t=39840 to
# /showthread.php?t=39840
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]+)/?$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```